# NHibernate 3.2 mapping by convention generating an unnecessary foreign key column

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a couple of classes that look like this:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class User
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public Client Client {get;set;}
}
```

I'm using ConventionModelMapper and SchemaUpdate from NHibernate 3.2 to generate the schema in my SQL Server database and I want the Client property of the User class to be mapped to a `ClientId` column with foreign key. My convention code looks like this:

```
mapper.AfterMapManyToOne += (inspector, member, map) =>
{
    map.Column(member.LocalMember.Name + "Id");
    // ...
};
```

This works, in that I get a column `ClientId` that is mapped as a foreign key, but I also end up with a `Client` column that is also mapped as a foreign key. It seems that NHibernate is treating the Client property as both a standard Property (and thus generating the `Client` column for it), and also a ManyToOne property (resulting in the additional `ClientId` column). How can I prevent the `Client` column from being generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just copied your EXACT code and, after making the properties virtual, the behavior is the expected (there's a single column, ClientId)